# Understanding pattern matching on lists

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching, extractor

I've been playing around with Extractors lately and was wondering how the List extractors work especially this:

```
List(1, 2, 3) match {
  case x :: y :: z :: Nil => x + y + z // case ::(x, ::(y, ::(z , Nil)))
}
```

Ok :: is used in the pattern, so I guess that the compiler now looks up the unapply method in the ::-Object. So tried this:

```
scala> (::).unapply(::(1, ::(2, Nil)))
res3: Option[(Int, List[Int])] = Some((1,List(2)))
```

Nice that works. However this does not:

```
scala> (::).unapply(List(1,2,3))      
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.::[?]
       (::).unapply(List(1,2,3))
```

while this does:

```
scala> List.unapplySeq(List(1,2,3))
res5: Some[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Actually I'm a little puzzled at the moment. How does the compiler choose the right implementation of unapply here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Match is basically doing the following:

```
(::).unapply(List[Int](1,2,3).asInstanceOf[::[Int]])
```

once it knows that it's safe (because `List(1,2,3).isInstanceOf[::[Int]]` is `true`).

Comment: And the compiler tries this because :: is a subtype of List? Update: Ah I think I get it ^^.

Comment: @raichoo - It tries it because you ask for `::` in the pattern.